# How to detect element is present within viewport? (Capybara, ruby)

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a step that checks for the footer visibility here

```
And (/^the footer appears$/) do
   within("div.footer") do
      assert_selector "a", :text=> "About"
      ...
   end
end
```

Basically I load the page and scroll to the bottom then do this check, but I also noticed that this steps works without me having to scroll to the bottom. I did some testing and found out this step only checks for visibility on the entire page. It doesn't check for visibility within the viewport.

I want to have a check that passes only when the element is within the viewport. Is this possible without Rspec and just capybara/ruby/js alone?

Comment: It's unlikely to be supported out of the box. It's possible with a JavaScript injection by comparing the rectangle returned by `element.getBoundingClientRect()` with the `window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight`. Another way it to call `elementFromPoint()` at the location and assert that the returned element is your element or a descendant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#evaluate_javascript` to check this.  Something along the lines of

```
in_view = evaluate_script("(function(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 && rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  )
})(arguments[0]);", find('div.footer'))
# assert that in_view is true, or whatever you want.
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Its something I been scratching my head over for a day. Mostly figuring out why assert_selector "div.footer", :visible=>true doesn't work with viewport visibility xD

Comment: My actual test case is that I wanted to test the stickiness of an element, like a header navigation element

Comment: @Nils_e assert_selector doesn’t consider viewport because every user has a different window size so it’s generally irrelevant